# Sideways Table not created - Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tables, errors, rotating

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hang]{caption2}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{psboxit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{colortab}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\renewcommand{\textwidth}{135mm}
\renewcommand{\textheight}{195mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
31 & 32 & 33 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

errors:

```
line 23: ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> \let \begin
line 23: ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again> \let \begin
```

Comment: Use package `geometry` to set up the paper and page margins. Those are lengths, not commands.

Comment: And please pay attention to the warning concerning `caption2`.

Comment: Use `\setlength{\textwidth}{135mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{195mm}` instead of `\renewcommand`. And preferably, as @Johannes_B said, use the `gemetry` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need any dimensions settings, besides `\textwidth` and `\textheight` are not commands as noted in Bernard's comment. See this:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{psboxit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{colortab}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
31 & 32 & 33 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

No warning pops up and I don't use any geometry setting.

However, if you really need to set lengths, it is best to use the two commands `\newgeometry` followed by your table then `\restoregeometry` below the table. Now See this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{psboxit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{colortab}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\begin{document}

\newgeometry{textwidth=135mm,textheight=195mm}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
31 & 32 & 33 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

There are no warnings too.

Finally consider removing the obsolete `caption2` package

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=135mm,textheight=195mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
31 & 32 & 33 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```